# MVC5 WebApi2 (OWIN) and WebAuthenticationBroker in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having issues with authenticating from a Windows Store App with the AccountController in a MVC5 WEBAPI2 solution. I am using the standard code generated when creating a new ASP.NET project for a WEBAPI.

I am using WebAuthenticationBroker to authenticate the user and have configured Microsoft authentication in the Startup.Auth.cs using UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication.

Everything seems to work up to the point where the AccountController.GetExternalLogin method needs to issue the token. I am authenticated successfully and a new identity is created with the “Bearer” authentication type, however a 200 OK is issued instead of the expected 302 redirect with the bearer token.

I am using Fiddler2 to compare the SPA application against the Windows Store application. The difference in fiddler between the two are that the /api/account/externallogin request responds with a 302 with the issued token when called from browser and a 200 ok response without the bearer token when called from the Windows Store App.

I use the URL created from the /api/account/externallogins to make the request, which is exactly the same for both scenarios. The only thing I can find that is different is the user agent header.

It seems to me like the OWIN middle-ware is not issuing the 302 redirect when the request originated from the Windows Store App, and returns the 200 OK from the action itself. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here are the two requests which initiates the workflow:
From the SPA application:

```
GET /api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Microsoft&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fflo.p1e.me%3A58546%2F&state=BS7KabYeygoz9t3Iqsruc1S9UccJP35-CTNnW9h43SM1 HTTP/1.1
```

From the Windows Store App:

```
GET /api/Account/ExternalLogin/?provider=Microsoft&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=ms-app%3A%2F%2Fs-1-15-2-2064878076-3984620318-3112860537-1772958928-95178788-1397955450-1148366612%2F&state=bKHK18Oo_Xv8PeFoPbfiInrV9lU70oRfNGypTw9z8701 HTTP/1.1
```

I have used the same redirect_uri for both calls with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by removing the trailing / after the action in the URL.

Before:

```
GET /api/Account/ExternalLogin/?provider=Microsoft&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=ms-app%3A%2F%2Fs-1-15-2-2064878076-3984620318-3112860537-1772958928-95178788-1397955450-1148366612%2F&state=bKHK18Oo_Xv8PeFoPbfiInrV9lU70oRfNGypTw9z8701 HTTP/1.1
```

After:

```
GET /api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Microsoft&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=ms-app%3A%2F%2Fs-1-15-2-2064878076-3984620318-3112860537-1772958928-95178788-1397955450-1148366612%2F&state=bKHK18Oo_Xv8PeFoPbfiInrV9lU70oRfNGypTw9z8701 HTTP/1.1
```